# How to inspect the CSS file in Angular 5 or line to change CSS if we want any CSS?

Tags: html, css, angular

I am making project in Angular 5. When I inspect the CSS there is  tag. If we want to change or find out that CSS is coming from which file basically or which line number of that file (like we do in normal html page). How can I find it?

Comment: its same as we do in normal html pages.use inspect element in the browser. @Tushar Jadhav

Answer (score 0):

With angular, the CSS is injected straight into the html page during compilation.

Therefor it's not possible to see where the CSS came from with the DevTools.

However, it is possible to see the CSS styles applied to an element, if you want to find out which file it came from, you will have to search the project.(`ctrl+shift+f`)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Google Chrome, you can use the developer console. Safari has a similar interface, but I'm not as familiar with that.

To access the developer console on Chrome, use keys Cmd-Option-I and you should see a console pop up on the right of your browser window. Next, if it isn't already selected, select the Elements tab at the top. You should now see the html that your browser rendered into the site.

Next, you'll want to select the element you want to inspect. You can either do this by accessing the nested HTML structure directly, or if you select the mouse icon at the top left of the window, you can select an element on the webpage and it will be expanded in the developer console.

Once you've selected an element (it should be grey/blue highlighted), you can see its styling at the bottom of your tab. The styling is in decreasing hierarchy order: the top elements override the bottom ones. You can see the styling is grouped based off of the id/class that it is applied to and at the top of each section is the file line of from which the styling came. Click that link to see the file!